Cannot remove margin while printing in IOS
I am developing a document creator with React. It is special product for my customer. Here is the CSS code of printed part of page in @media print:
.print-content {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 210mm;
    height: 297mm;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

I added border to debug the issue. Issue is that: It works on Windows, Android, even with Chrome on Mac (I think reason is desktop chrome uses own printer). However, it does not work on IPhone, IPad and Safari on Mac. I know that @page does not work with IOS (it solves the margin problem in Android) but I need to remove margins. Here is the screenshot from an Ipad (I censored document content and footers):
Screenshoot
As you can see, It adds some margin to my A4 content. How can I remove that margins?
I tried to use @page {margin: 0 !important;}, it worked on Android but did not work on IOS.

Can you create a runnable snippet so we can see the problem for ourselves on IOS (use <> icon in the editor).
